# font awesome icon input group inside field

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I cannot get this icon to sit inside the field, I can only get it either above or below:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group addon">
                <i class="fa fa-user">
                </i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

.form-group i{
  color: #ccc;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I have tried reading nearly every post on here but I am getting quite frustrated.

Comment: Could you please share the jfFiddle?

Answer (score 8):

I think what you were looking for was the class **`"input-group-prepend"`** This is from **v 4.0.0** I don't know how it was done in previous versions. I think with the **addon** class like mentioned in previous answers, but this is what works for me:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
     </div>
   </div>
```

***Here is a full `form` demonstration with 3 `input` fields:***

```
     <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
              </div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
          </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block btn-lg">
     </form>
```

***... and the final result is:***

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `input-group-addon` class like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group addon">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group addon">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQdMKW)

Comment: @nowox yes, this question is about Bootstrap 3, in Bootstrap 4 you have to use different markup, look here: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good, Bootstrap 4 does not expose this feature but it actually has class inside. All you need to do is just add the class "**input-group-text**" next to "**input-group addon**".

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group addon input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-user">
            </i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing was working then I found this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```
<div class="form-group">    
      <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
      <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputFirstName">
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the css link of font-awesome before the bootstrap link.